# To remove double quotes from date string in SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using `JSON_EXTRACT()` to retrieve the date from json.

I want to get the date without double quotes.

Here is the example of what I am doing :

```
JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(events, "$.my_member"), "$.my_Number") as xyz
```

`my_number` holds date string as "2016-01-01 11:31:25", I want this without the double quotes.

I tried using timestamp as :

```
timestamp(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(events, "$.my_member"), "$.my_Number"))
```

but it is returning a null value to xyz.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `REPLACE`

```
REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(events, "$.my_member"), "$.my_Number"),"\"","") as xyz
```

Answer (score 30):

Try

```
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(JSON_EXTRACT(events, "$.my_member"), "$.my_Number")
```

Also, you should be able to further "optimize" your expression by building proper JSON Path and using JSON function only ones. See "hint" below

```
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(
    '{"my_member":{"my_Number":"2016-01-01 11:31:25"}}', 
    "$.my_member.my_Number"
  )
```

See more details and also difference between JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR and JSON_EXTRACT at [JSON functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#jsonfunctions)

Comment: This is the correct answer. The SCALAR version is intended for extracting scalar values like strings.

Comment: I used JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR in MySQL Workbench and got Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION manifest.JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR does not exist.  I may be doing something wrong (please LMK if I have).  I found an alternative solution which I have posted below.

Comment: this was BigQuery tagged question! :o)

Answer (score 0):

I tried JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR in MySQL Workbench but I got Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION manifest.JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR does not exist

Instead I used JSON_UNQUOTE and that did the trick.

I have a column called 'buffer_time' which contains:

```
'{"after": {"time": "00:01:00", "is_enabled": true}, "before": {"time": "00:04:00", "is_enabled": true}}'
```

JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(buffer_time, '$.after.time'))
gave me:  `

> `00:01:00`

Hope that helps.